# How to get the Table result from the store procedure?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have tried to write the store procedure with some condition check inside the `Where` syntax.

But it only shows the status of the query instead of result.

Could any body help to resolve this issue.

Please find the query

```
declare @query varchar(200)
declare @option varchar(10) = 'A'
set @query ='select * from TableName'+
(case when @query = ''
then
'where ColumnName = 1 '
end)
execute sp_sqlexec @query
```

Comment: where is you c# code

Comment: Me tried it in the SQL syntax only

Answer (score 2):

Your query should be

```
declare @query varchar(200)
declare @option varchar(10) ='A'
declare @search as int=1 

select @query ='select * from TableName '+
case when @option ='A'
then
' where ColumnName = '+ cast(@search as varchar(200))
else ''
end
execute sp_sqlexec @query
```

<kbd>**[see demo](http://rextester.com/GTH23991)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks for the reply. it working for me but while using the parameter inside the query showing declaration error. but me already register my local parameter

Comment: See demo [http://rextester.com/GTH23991] Works here. Please post the error

Comment: Please find the code:

--declare `@query` varchar(200)

--declare `@option` varchar(10) = 'A'

--declare `@search` as int=1

--set `@query` ='select * from TableName '

--if `@option` ='A' set @query = @query + ' where ColumnName =  `@search'`
--execute sp_sqlexec `@query`

Comment: Please accept my reply as correct answer if it worked for you- so that other users can benefit: from knowing that the answer works and by having the question marked as Answered.

Answer (score 0):

What i can see for sure is lack of space before where condition.

```
declare @query varchar(200)
declare @option varchar(10) = 'A'
set @query ='select * from TableName'+
(case when @query = ''
then
' where ColumnName = 1 '
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this :

```
declare @query varchar(200)

declare @option varchar(10) = 'A'

set @query ='select * from TableName '

if @option ='A'
   set @query = @query + ' where ColumnName = 1 '

--print @query

execute sp_sqlexec @query
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare     @query  nvarchar(max)
        ,   @option varchar(10)     = 'A';

set @query = N'select * from TableName '
           + CASE WHEN @option IS NOT NULL
                THEN N' where ColumnName = 1 ' ELSE N'' END

execute sp_executesql @query;
```

Avoid using `sp_sqlexec` it is very old and not supported anymore, use sp_executesql instead.